# global name 'decimalmessage' is not defined

Tags: python, flask

I have this code is about ntru crptosystem and I want to use decimalmessage out of the `on_message()` but when I used global to that I have this error: `global name 'decimalmessage' is not defined`.

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from ntru1 import *
import sys
import json
import threading
import signal
# Define the NTRU parameters and generate Bob's public key
Bob = Ntru(167, 3, 128)
f = [1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1]
g = [-1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1]
d = 2
Bob.genPublicKey(f, g, 2)
pub_key = Bob.getPublicKey()
print("Public Key:", pub_key)

# Send Bob's public key to Alice using MQTT
data_out = json.dumps(pub_key)
mqttc = mqtt.Client()
mqttc.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)
if mqttc.connect("localhost", 1883, 60) != 0:
    print('dis')
    sys.exit(-1)
mqttc.publish("test", data_out, 0)
mqttc.disconnect()
msga=0
# Define the on_message() function to handle incoming messages
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    
    global decimalmessage
        
    msga=json.loads(msg.payload)
    print("Received encrypted message:", msg.payload)
    encrypted_message = json.loads(msg.payload)
    decrypted_message = Bob.decrypt(encrypted_message)
    print("Decrypted message:", decrypted_message)
        #from binary to decmail
        
    decimalmessage=str(int(''.join(map(str,decrypted_message)),2))
    print(decimalmessage)


# Define the MQTT client 

def mqtt_thread():
    global client 
    client= mqtt.Client()
    client.on_message = on_message
    print("hree",msga)
    if client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60) != 0:
        print('dis')
        sys.exit(-1)
    client.subscribe("test2")

    client.loop_forever()
    
# Start the MQTT client thread
mqtt_client_thread = threading.Thread(target=mqtt_thread)
mqtt_client_thread.start()
print(decimalmessage)


# Run the Flask application in the main thread
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def inde():
    f1 = f
    g1 = g
    bob2 = Bob
    publkey = pub_key
    return render_template("index.html", f1=f1, g1=g1, bob2=bob2, publkey=publkey)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.37', port=4457, debug=True)ere
```

Comment: Well at the point the line `print(decimalmessage)` is encountered, `decimalmessage` is not yet defined by a call to `onmessage`.

Comment: You have started a thread that may, eventually, assign a value to `decimalmessage` (only if a message is received).  You then proceed to *immediately* try to print the value of `decimalmessage` - how could that possibly work?

Comment: I used python 2.7